# Help with VERY broken Wordpress permalinks for Categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

I have a very strange wordpress permalink problem.  I noticed that the category permalinks don't work right at all anymore (and they used to).

My .htaccess and wp-config file are brand new and up to date, and I don't have any caching currently turned on.

This category defaults to blog post:
/blog/category/blogging

but it shows fine in non-pretty-permalink format:
/?cat=4

This category shows page not found:
/category/monetization/

but it shows fine in non-pretty-permalink format:
/?cat=25

my site is jtpratt.com - you can check the issues out live there right now.

I have a category dropdown in the sidebar, if you select different categories, some are displayed working in the ?cat=ID format, and others in normal permalinks.  How a dropdown does that - I don't know.

I reverted to the default 2010 WP theme, had the same problem with category pages.  Also deactivated ALL plugins, had the same problem.

I think that somehow the permalinks actually stored IN the database are screwed up - and I think this because I had a page earlier today that no matter how many times I updated it, wouldn't show the changes on the front end.  I had to copy the content, send the page to the trash AND delete it there, and recreate and republish the page to get it to show up.

I build WP web sites for a living (7 years WP experience), and I can't figure this out.

Any ideas?

Comment: check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com !

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing all permalink rules from .htaccess and clear the permalink settings in the wp_options table in the database via phpmyadmin; usually option_id 34. Then reset permalinks. I've had to do that in the past to fix stuck permalink problems.